# How paypal payment flow will go? Is it possible to auto-generate paypal links?

Tags: paypal

I'm interested in using paypal to process my payments.

The payments will either be single time only or recurring (maybe some sort of checkbox for recurring vs. non-recurring).

I have a product price in my own database I want to use in paypal, and I have a subscription length in months in my database that I would like to use in paypal.

Is there a way in paypal to, based on my own information

- Set the price of the transaction based on db value
- Set as a recurring or 1-time payment. [form checkbox]
- Set number of months of subscription length based on db value (paypal billingcycle)

If this is not possible what is recommended for me to do?

I would love if I could just auto-generate some link.

I found this: http://www.blogbyben.com/2009/04/paypal-link-generator-build-your-own-1.html
http://www.itaynoy.com/sites/paypal_button_generator/

but I need to be able to add more options like subscription length and recurring billing.

Thanks.

Comment: if paypal can't do this would authorize.net be able to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to dynamically generate a PayNow button? If so, this thread may be of some use to you:
[automatically create buy now button paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348761/automatically-create-buy-now-button-paypal)